# IBM Worklight 6.1- [ERROR ] FWLSE0020E and [ERROR ] FWLSE0117E

Tags: eclipse, ibm-mobilefirst, worklight-studio

I'm using worklight 6.1 for my mobile app project. Why do I get this error message when preview in Eclipse?

Error message:

```
[ERROR   ] FWLSE0020E: Ajax request exception: The application 'example' with version=1.0 does not support the android environment [project example]

[ERROR   ] FWLSE0117E: Error code: 1, error description: INTERNAL_ERROR, error message: FWLSE0069E: An internal error occurred during gadget request  [project example]The application 'example' with version=1.0 does not support the android environment, User Identity {SubscribeServlet=null, wl_authenticityRealm=null, wl_remoteDisableRealm=null, SampleAppRealm=null, wl_antiXSRFRealm=null, wl_deviceAutoProvisioningRealm=null, WorklightConsole=null, wl_deviceNoProvisioningRealm=null, wl_anonymousUserRealm=null}. [project example]

com.worklight.common.log.filters.ErrorFilter
```

Comment: Did you add the Android environment to your app? Did you then build and deploy the app?

Comment: Still got same error.

Comment: Did this app work in the past? What did you recently change in it? When did this error begin to appear?

Comment: It work in past. But when I integrate with worklight adapter into my main.js, I got this error.

Comment: Please export the Worklight project and upload to Dropbox.

Comment: check this out https://github.com/datomnurdin/worklight-mobile/archive/master.zip

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your project works perfectly fine for me in Worklight 6.1.0.

I've created a new Eclipse workspace and imported the project into it.
I then:

- Right-clicked on the adapter folder ("UserId") and chose Run As > Deploy Worklight adapter
- Right-clicked on the application folder ("WokrlightMobile") and chose Run As > Run on Worklight Development Server

I continued to load to the Worklight Console, clicked on the Android preview icon and application loaded in the MBS. I also received a "success" dialog from the adapter.

Try in a fresh workspace.

Comment: tqvm idan. I just need run on Worklight Development Server

Comment: Thx this has helped me

Comment: Worked for me after I ran the Worklight Development server after deploying the adapters. Thanks @Idan Adar

Answer (score -1):

I solved the issue by increasing the version number of both the Android and iPhone app.