# Error while running worklight project in windows phone 8

Tags: windows-phone-8, ibm-mobilefirst

```
[ERROR   ] FWLSE0020E: Ajax request exception: There is no application in the DB with the id 'MFS'. [project MFS]

[ERROR   ] FWLSE0117E: Error code: 1, error description: INTERNAL_ERROR, error message: 

FWLSE0069E: An internal error occurred during gadget request  [project MFS]
There is no application in the DB with the id 'MFS'., User Identity {SubscribeServlet=null, 
wl_authenticityRealm=null, wl_remoteDisableRealm=null, SampleAppRealm=null, 
wl_antiXSRFRealm=null, wl_deviceAutoProvisioningRealm=null, WorklightConsole=null, 
wl_deviceNoProvisioningRealm=null, wl_anonymousUserRealm=null}. [project MFS]

com.worklight.common.log.filters.ErrorFilter
```

Comment: Really nice to only paste an error without any descriptive text. -1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems to be the same error as in this question: [IBM Worklight 6.1- [ERROR ] FWLSE0020E and [ERROR ] FWLSE0117E](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21128463/ibm-worklight-6-1-error-fwlse0020e-and-error-fwlse0117e)

The error is clear. Did you make sure to deploy the application?
Right-click the application folder and choose Run As > Run on Worklight Development Server.

Also try to import your project into a fresh new workspace.

---

From the comments to this answer (no thanks to the very poor quality of the question), it looks like the actual problem the user encounters is when navigating a multi-page application in Windows Phone 8.

The solution for this is to follow the training module as well as sample project (below), which contain special handling exactly for this issue:

- [training module](http://public.dhe.ibm.com/software/mobile-solutions/worklight/docs/v610/03_02_Building_a_multi_page_application.pdf)
- [sample project](http://public.dhe.ibm.com/software/mobile-solutions/worklight/docs/v610/BuildingMultiPageApplicationProject.zip)

Comment: In windows phone 8 we have to provide full path to load page?

Comment: I don't understand the question. This error is not about Windows Phone 8, but about not building and deploying the project in Worklight Studio.

Comment: $("#pagePort").load("www/default/pages/login.html", function () {
     $.getScript("www/default/js/login.js", function () {
         if (currentPage.init) {
             currentPage.init();
         }
     });
 });

www/default/pages/login.html - i provide this path working
pages/login.html - i provide this path not working in windows phone 8 (working fine for android and iOS)

Comment: Okay, listen, EDIT YOUR QUESTION and explain what you are trying TO DO  in your application. And also mention your Worklight version. The multipage sample project provided in the IBM Worklight training modules webpage contains special handling for exactly this issue.

Comment: If your original question is answered, please mark this as ANSWERED. Do not mix questions.